# Is there any escape symbol for { in JSON?

Tags: c#, json, rest, api

I am using rest api and using content type as `JSON`. 
I am giving some value to POST method with `{` in it. So , it giving out as bad request. 
So, it is possible to escape `{` and print the following

> "MISSING VALUES: Please put the description of the with mandatory
>   field {code} \n StudentId {code}"

Comment: I would suggest you utilize classes to handle your serialize and deserializing of the JSON data. [here](http://json2csharp.com)

Comment: Without the value you are sending , it is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no special escape character for `{` or `}` since the only valid place for them to be is in the JSON structure to denote the begin or end of an object, or in strings where they don't need escaping. They are not allowed as field names so no need to escape them.

I guess there is something else wrong with your request.

Comment: When i am giving without {code} its giving me a required result. But when i am using {code} its giving a bad request. i am using  {code} for better appearance while giving a rest call.

Comment: What is on the other end?

Comment: Edit your question or add a comment and add the json you are having problems with.